# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException : refactoring code to use AsyncTask?

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I am getting the error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` , I know the fix is to run my code in `AsnycTask`.

I do not know how to refactor the following code to use `AsnycTask`? Can I do all this in the one `activity`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.tvTitle)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.etName)
    EditText name;
    @Bind(R.id.etEmail)
    EditText email;
    @Bind(R.id.etIdea)
    EditText idea;
    @Bind(R.id.btnSubmit)
    Button submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get input from editText boxes to send to php file on server
                String  toSubmit = name.getText().toString() + " " + email.getText().toString() + " " + idea.getText().toString();

                try{
                    getData(toSubmit);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static InputStream toInputStream(String input, String encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = encoding != null ? input.getBytes(encoding) : input.getBytes();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    }

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        long count = copyLarge(input, output);
        if (count > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return -1;
        }
        return (int) count;
    }

    String getData(String postData) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder respData = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("MY_URL");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

        httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "YourApp"); 
        httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);

        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        InputStream postStream = toInputStream(postData, "UTF-8");
        try {
            copy(postStream, os);
        } finally {
            postStream.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }

        httpUrlConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (200 == responseCode) {
            InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = isr.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    respData.append(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            } finally {
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            is.close();
        }
        else {
            // use below to get error stream
            // inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
        }
        return respData.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: yes it is possible to write AsyncTask in same `Activity`. See this link for more info. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Do i just put the pull code in it? thanks

Comment: No. not the entire code. Have a look at it. If it's not useful, I can think of an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for the android documented usage of this but it basically boils down to the following implementation:

A private subclass which extends AsyncTask which Implements the following methods:

1. `onPreExecute` – Invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed and is used for setting stuff up (e.g showing the progress bar)
2. `doInBackground` – The actual operation you want to perform which is fired immediately after onPreExecute
3. `onPostExecute` – Invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground completes. This takes in the result from doInBackground as a parameter and can then be used on the UI thread.

An AsyncTask is used for operations which aren’t permitted on the UI thread such as:

- Opening a socket connection
- HTTP requests (such as HTTPClient and HTTPURLConnection)
- Attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database
- Downloading a file

Your current code is sitting in a method which will be created on the UI thread (which will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, so you need to move your code over to a thread which is running on a `worker` thread.

**Moving your code over to an AsyncTask**

By the looks of things, only your `getData()` method needs to be rearranged. Everything regarding retrieving the data can go in the `doInBackground` bit of the task, and all updating of UI components (such as your `toast`) need to be moved to the `onPostExecute`.

It should look something like the following (note a few things may need to be tweaked. This was written away from a compiler):

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Value> 
{
    boolean success = false;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String toSubmit) 
    {
        StringBuilder respData = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("MY_URL");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

        httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "YourApp"); 
        httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);

        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        InputStream postStream = toInputStream(toSubmit, "UTF-8");
        try {
            copy(postStream, os);
        } finally {
            postStream.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }

        httpUrlConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (200 == responseCode) {
            InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = isr.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    respData.append(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            } finally {
                if (isr != null)
                {
                    isr.close();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            is.close();
        }
        else {
            // use below to get error stream
            // inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
        }
        return respData.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        processValue(result);
    }
}

private void processValue(String theResult) 
{
   //handle value
}

String toSubmit = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get input from editText boxes to send to php file on server
            toSubmit = name.getText().toString() + " " + email.getText().toString() + " " + idea.getText().toString();

            try{
                new MyTask().execute();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, does getData go into doInBackground? Im quite confused by it

Comment: Pretty much. Where you originally call `getData(toSubmit);` you should execute the AsyncTask. 

The `doInBackground` of the task can take your `String postData` as a parameter, and the result of that will be passed to `onPostExecute`. From there you could update a public variable which is visible by the outer class (as well as triggering your `toast` - perhaps through a success boolean updated by the result of the task in `doInBackground`)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i do not follow you, can you please post some sample code relating to my example. Im not trying to be lazy Im just having trouble understanding, I appreciate it!

Comment: Of course! It's pretty confusing stuff at first. I'll update my original answer with some code (might need altering slightly to compile with what you have already)

Comment: Thank you for a complete example. What should I put in for the line: httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "YourApp");  ?

Comment: In your original code? You may get away with something like `System.setProperty("http.agent", "");`. For future reference, there is a site specifically for this: http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: Thanks, Can you please take a look at my problem with the code in my recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618210/sending-string-data-to-php-file-on-server-string-is-not-sent?noredirect=1#comment55011005_33618210 , I cannot get it to work yet using the example you posted! I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. I'll take a look at the question. By the way. up-votes are always appreciated if an answer has been helpful or good! ;)

Comment: Thanks I have upvoted! Please note that I have now changed the PHP file so I think the issue is with the Android code! I really appreciate this help!