# Sending string data to PHP file on server: string is not sent?

Tags: php, android, post, android-asynctask, get

I am attempting to send a `string` to a `PHP` file on a remote server using `POST` and `GET, the PHP then writes the string to a text file.

My code (below) compiles and runs without error, however when the submit button is pressed there is **no action**. I.e. the `toast` does not display and when I check the `text file` that is written to from my `PHP` file on the server, there is nothing.

Am I missing something very *obvious* that would cause this not to work? (note: "my_url" is there on purpose, that is not the error)

**Android Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.tvTitle)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.etName)
    EditText name;
    @Bind(R.id.etEmail)
    EditText email;
    @Bind(R.id.etIdea)
    EditText idea;
    @Bind(R.id.btnSubmit)
    Button submit;

    String toSubmit = "";
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      try{
                            new MyTask().execute();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        long count = copyLarge(input, output);
        if (count > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return -1;
        }
        return (int) count;
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        boolean success = false;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            StringBuilder respData = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection;
            URLConnection conn;
            URL url;

            try {

                url = new URL("my_url/recieveString.php");
                conn = url.openConnection();
                httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

                httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                //httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "App");
                httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();

                toSubmit = "test";

                stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(toSubmit.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                copy(stream, os);

                httpUrlConnection.connect();

                int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (200 == responseCode) {
                    InputStream is = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = null;
                    try {
                        isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = isr.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            respData.append(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (isr != null) {
                            isr.close();
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                    is.close();
                } else {
                    // use below to get error stream
                    //inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                stream.close();
                os.flush();

                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "done";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    }

}
```

**PHP file:**

```
<?php 

$stringRecieved=$_GET["toSubmit"]; 

$file = 'list.txt';

// Write the contents to the file, 
file_put_contents($file, $stringRecieved, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Comment: Although you can mix GET and POST, it seems unlikely here that you are doing that. Based on the android code it would seem that you are using POST so you would need to access `$_POST` in php.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? does `isr` have any value after the request?

Comment: No I could not see a value for it after the request?

Comment: Can you see anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you see anything else wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are POSTing to the server the variable will not be in GET.

```
$stringRecieved = $_POST["toSubmit"];
```

Incidentally, it is usually a good idea to provide a wrapper and test that POST is actually being used; it's usually a good idea to sanitize input, and it's usually a good idea to make sure that access is coming from a valid source, none of which your PHP seems to be doing yet.

Comment: Why not include the spaces for readability? ```$stringRecieved = $_POST["toSubmit"];```

Comment: Because I cut'n pasted it from his code, rather in a hurry.  Fixed. :-)

Comment: Hi thanks, I have changed the php file but it still is not working. Can you see an error in the android code? Sorry I am a beginner this is my first experience with anything expect a very basic app!

Comment: No Droid programming experience here.  Why is this commented out though?   ''' //inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream(); '''

I'd think you'd want to know if there are any errors at this stage.